# Left join to an inner join without a string in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm attempting to construct a query in Rails 5.1.3 that left joins an association to an association I've inner joined - see pseudocode example with below models

```
# Foo has_many :bar
# Bar belongs_to :foo; has_many :baz
# Baz belongs_to :bar
Foo.joins(Bar.left_joins(:baz)) # obviously doesn't work, but that's the gist
```

Normally this is doable by writing a custom join as a string, i.e. `Foo.joins(:bar).joins("bar LEFT OUTER JOINS baz ON etc etc")`, but doing this prevents ActiveRecord from aliasing the table in the event that it needs to be referenced elsewhere in the query. That inability to alias is causing "table referenced multiple times" errors in my application.

I've tried aliasing the table in the join string as well, but doing so prevents me from applying filters to that table in the query without exposing the name of the alias.

Is there a way to left join a table to a table that has already been inner joined without using raw SQL strings (i.e. with native ActiveRecord)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Includes will produce a left outer join. Try something like:

```
Foo.joins(:bars).includes(bars: :bazs)
```

Comment: Cheers - I had assumed it'd create duplicate left joins if i restated the whole relationship in the `includes`, but it looks like `Foo.joins(bar: :baz).includes(bar: {baz: :qux})` resolves inner/left outer joins properly.